# Samsung syncing messages but not contacts on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, contacts, sync, restore

I messed up bad and lost all my contacts/messages when I tried to install another OS on my Samsung Galaxy S3. Now I have gotten the operating system back and Samsung Account let me retrieve my messages.

But not my contacts. I've checked all my Google accounts that I might have had synced on the phone using my PC web browser, but none of them had any contacts.

**Is there any way to restore my contacts via Samsung? Or any chance I could restore them another way?**

If anyone cares to hear the (almost) whole story in short:

1. I decided to change OS and so I rooted the phone (never done any of this   before) and made backups with Titanium Backup (TiBa).
2. I couldn't restore the contacts to the new OS with TiBa, guessing because it was only for the old OS.
3. So I reinstalled my old OS but it wouldn't boot so I had to do a factory reset as well. Which I heard would leave my data on the SD card untouched.
4. Well it didn't. So I lost my backups as well. I should have moved it to the computer, but I was lazy and had already started to install the old OS.
5. Luckily, I can at least get all my messages back because of the synced data.

**Edit:** Ah, also, before I did any other backup (which I lost) I did copy everything from my phone to my PC  using Windows Explorer, but I don't think that included my contacts. I have a folder  `.../Android/data/com.android.contacts`  but it's empty except for an empty cache folder.

Comment: It sounds like the contacts were saved as "phone-only" (unsynced) contacts. If that's the case, since all your backups are gone, I'm afraid you're out of luck. But I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah. That's probably the case. Darn. How can I keep my messages then, when I change to the newer OS this time?